# .NET Sort List<> with associated array

Tags: .net, arrays, list, generics, sorting

I'd like to sort a `List<string>`, but at the same time sort a `float[]` array: which are the associated values. (I know this is bad design, it is so historically). So whenever two items are swapped in the List I would like the values at the indexes in the array also swapped. There's a method for doing this with two arrays: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa311223%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
However I can't find anything for a List and an array: is there such a method somewhere?

Comment: There's not much benefit in having a `List<string>` if it has to twin to a `float[]`. Frankly, I would either use a `string[]` and use the two-array sort, or (more likely) I'd create a type (possibly a `struct`) that is composed of a `string` and a `float`, and just use a `List<ThatNewType>` (and `.Sort()` at will).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) (.NET 4.0 and above) to merge the list and array and perform the sort on the result.

---

Update:

Since you are using .NET 3.5, you can use `Array.Sort`, as you have linked to, converting the list to an array first:

```
var stringArray = myStringList.ToArray();
Array.Sort(stringArray, myFloatArray);
```

The way I would normally do this, however, would be with creating a type holding a `string` and `float`, and use that in a generic collection to sort.

Comment: Interesting, but we're using .NET3.5 unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Oded beat me to it: I was also going to suggest copying the list into a `SortedList<string, float>` then use `.Keys` to get the list sorted back and `.Values` to get the floats back in the corresponding order. These don't return an actual List and array so you might need to `.ToList` and `.ToArray` the values unless you can use the results as `IList` or `IEnumerable` instead.

You could also write a custom Sort function that manages both lists together. Or just bite the bullet and refactor the code to store these properly!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can `ToArray` your list and use the example you provided in the question. Then `new List<string>(stringArray)` when you are done.

Not the way I would tackle the problem personally, but a valid alternative.